# Installing VirtualBox 6.1.22 conflicts with installed 6.0.20

Tags: centos, virtualbox, upgrade

On my CentOS 7 installation I am looking to upgrade VM VirtualBox. The downloaded installer runs through `yum` and asks permission to install. However the installation fails with a `Transaction check error`, where generally

`file /.../...6.1.22... conflicts with file from package /.../...6.0.20...`

But I don't want them to be compatible, I just want to install the new version. Why is the upgrade failing?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the 6.0.20 version did not remove any configurations or virtual machines, they were available on installation of 6.1.22.